# Multiple UPDATE queries in Google BigQuery using python

Tags: python, google-bigquery

I'm trying to run multiple BigQuery queries via the python API but it seems like not all of them are being done, my guess is that I'm not giving them enough time to complete. What I have is something like:

```py
from google.cloud import bigquery
client = bigquery.Client()

query1 = "UPDATE ..."
client.query(query1)
query2 = "UPDATE ..."
client.query(query2)
query3 = "UPDATE ..."
client.query(query3)
```

My solution so far is inserting a sleep command before each client call, it works but it is kind of slow. Any hints or tips about how to do it on a more efficient way are appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

BigQuery uses asynchronous jobs for queries. That means you can submit your query but it hasn’t necessarily finished yet. You can wait for it to finish if the next update requires the previous one to be complete.

If they aren’t tightly coupled, just send all of your updates and then wait at the end and all should complete. The return object of a query is that job, so you can use that to check the status of any of your update commands.

[More info](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/bigquery/generated/google.cloud.bigquery.job.QueryJob.html#google.cloud.bigquery.job.QueryJob)

Answer (score 2):

If you return the job to a variable, you can use job.state or job.error_result to determine if the job has finished. Then you can do something like:

```
j = client.query(query1) 
 while j.state == 'RUNNING':
     time.sleep(10)
if j.error_result is not None:
    print(j.error_result)
    break
```

Can also use the ";" to run queries one after another

```
e.g. query1 = "select * from table1; select * from table2"
```

Answer (score 2):

If you just insert `query_job.result()` it will wait until the query is executed.

```
from google.cloud import bigquery
client = bigquery.Client()

query1 = "UPDATE ..."
query_job = client.query(query1)
query_job.result()

query2 = "UPDATE ..."
query_job = client.query(query2)
query_job.result()

query3 = "UPDATE ..."
query_job = client.query(query3)
query_job.result()
```

Personally I would rather write it a bit more compact

```
from google.cloud import bigquery
client = bigquery.Client()

queries = ["UPDATE ...", "UPDATE ...", "UPDATE ..."]
for query in queries:
    query_job = client.query(query)
    query_job.result()
```

Answer (score 1):

Now that BigQuery Scripting has been released, you can simply run all UPDATEs as a script:

```
from google.cloud import bigquery
client = bigquery.Client()

query1 = "UPDATE ..."
query1 += "UPDATE ..."
query1 += "UPDATE ..."
client.query(query1)
```